# Draw circle with php imagemagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I just want to get the basic idea of how to draw a circle with php5 imagemagick.
I have looked at the page, http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.circle.php
but the example there is too confusing. I want to just draw a circle then mess around with that. Can someone give me a simple php5 imagemagick circle example?

I have tried:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$circle = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->circle (10, 10, 60, 10);
//echo $circle;
?>
```

any numerous variants, but I cant get a circle drawn.

Comment: http://www.phpimagick.com/ImagickDraw/circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php
$draw = new ImagickDraw ();
//given that $x and $y are the coordinates of the centre, and $r the radius:
$draw->circle ($x, $y, $x + $r, $y);
?>
```

Comment: Man I really do not get it. Working example pls? x,y are origin? ok what are the other 2 x & y? $draw->circle (0,0,50,50,0);

Comment: try this $draw->circle (10, 10, 60, 10);

Comment: @j0h `x` and `y` is the center, the 2nd `x` and `y` is a point on the circumference.

Answer (score 1):

Danak on the php chat page provided me with this link, Which provides an active example.
http://www.phpimagick.com/ImagickDraw/circle

The variable names are concise and descriptive, 
and the example makes it easy for me to understand what is going on.

```
function circle($strokeColor, $fillColor, $backgroundColor, $originX, $originY, $endX, $endY) {

    //Create a ImagickDraw object to draw into.
    $draw = new \ImagickDraw();

    $strokeColor = new \ImagickPixel($strokeColor);
    $fillColor = new \ImagickPixel($fillColor);

    $draw->setStrokeOpacity(1);
    $draw->setStrokeColor($strokeColor);
    $draw->setFillColor($fillColor);

    $draw->setStrokeWidth(2);
    $draw->setFontSize(72);

    $draw->circle($originX, $originY, $endX, $endY);

    $imagick = new \Imagick();
    $imagick->newImage(500, 500, $backgroundColor);
    $imagick->setImageFormat("png");
    $imagick->drawImage($draw);

    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
```